# How to wrap data.table::fread in your own package, with bit64 capability?

Tags: r, package, data.table, bit64

I have a package containing a function that calls [`fread`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread) from `data.table`.  `data.table` has the `bit64` package in the Suggests field of its DESCRIPTION file, which gives `fread` the capability to import large integers as
`integer64` rather than `numeric`.  I need this capability by default in my package.

Here's a reproducible example, under R 3.1.3 (earlier versions don't have this issue).

---

#### Attempt 1

```
Vectorize(dir.create)(c("test", "test/R", "test/man"))

cat(
  "Package: test
Title: Test pkg
Description: Investigate how to use suggested package
Version: 0.0-1
Date: 2015-03-10
Author: Richie Cotton
Maintainer: Richie Cotton <a@b.com>
Imports: data.table
Suggests: bit64
License: Unlimited
",
  file = "test/DESCRIPTION"
)

cat(
  "#' Read data
#' 
#' Wrapper to \\code{fread} that loads bit64 first
#' @param ... Passed to fread.
#' @return A data frame of uniformly distributed random numbers and their index.
#' @importFrom data.table fread
#' @export
read_data <- function(...)
{
  library(bit64)
  fread(...)
}",
  file = "test/R/read_data.R"
)
```

When I run `R CMD check`,

```
library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)
roxygenize("test")
check("test")
```

I get the following `NOTE`:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
'library' or 'require' call to 'bit64' in package code.
Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.
See section 'Suggested packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

---

#### Attempt 2

The [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages) suggests replacing `library` with [`requireNamespace`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/requireNamespace).  This checks to see if the package exists, but doesn't load it onto R's search path.

If I update the definition of `read_data` to:

```
read_data <- function(...)
{
  if(!requireNamespace('bit64')) 
  {
    warning('bit64 not available.')
  }
  fread(...)
}
```

then `R CMD check` runs smoothly, but since `bit64` is now not loaded, `fread` doesn't have the ability to read long integers.

---

#### Attempt 3

If I change the `DESCRIPTION` so that `bit64` is in the `Depends` section (instead of `Suggests`, and keep `read_data` as in attempt 2, or simplify it to

```
read_data <- function(...)
{
  fread(...)
}
```

then `R CMD check` gives the `NOTE`:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Package in Depends field not imported from: 'bit64'
  These packages need to be imported from (in the NAMESPACE file)
  for when this namespace is loaded but not attached.
```

I'm not quite sure what I should be importing in this case.

---

#### Attempt 4

If I keep `bit64` in the `Depends` section, and use the original definition of `read_data`,

```
read_data <- function(...)
{
  library(bit64)
  fread(...)
}
```

then `R CMD check` gives the `NOTE`:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
'library' or 'require' call to 'bit64' which was already attached by Depends.
Please remove these calls from your code.
Package in Depends field not imported from: 'bit64'
```

---

I feel like there should be some magic combination of `DESCRIPTION` and function definitions that gives me the `bit64` functionality and passes `R CMD check` cleanly; I just can't see what I've missed.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need a NAMESPACE file that explicitly imports bit64 (or just the functions you want from the namespace). Put bit64 in the Depends DESCRIPTION field, add the NAMESPACE file, and this should work. See [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks.  roxygen2 was creating the NAMESPACE file for me; it just hadn't told it to import bit64.

Answer (score 4):

Attempt 3 was closest; I just needed an extra `@import bit64` in the roxygen documentation.

```
Vectorize(dir.create)(c("test", "test/R", "test/man"))

cat(
  "Package: test
Title: Test pkg
Description: Investigate how to use suggested package
Version: 0.0-1
Date: 2015-03-10
Author: Richie Cotton
Maintainer: Richie Cotton <a@b.com>
Depends: bit64
Imports: data.table
License: Unlimited
",
  file = "test/DESCRIPTION"
)

cat(
  "#' Read data
#' 
#' Wrapper to \\code{fread} that loads bit64 first
#' @param ... Passed to fread.
#' @return A data frame of uniformly distributed random numbers and their index.
#' @import bit64
#' @importFrom data.table fread
#' @export
read_data <- function(...)
{
  fread(...)
}",
  file = "test/R/read_data.R"
)
```